# Is the symmetry condition necessary to define the trace?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M^n,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold and $S\in\Gamma(\bigotimes^{0,2}TM)$ be **symmetric**. Then define the trace of $S$ to be a function $\operatorname{tr}S$ given by:
$$
\operatorname{tr}S(x)=\sum_{i}S(e_i,e_i),
$$
where $\{e_i\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $T_xM$. I need to show that above definition is independent of the choice of $\{e_i\}$.

Here is my approach. Let $\{\tilde{e}_i\}$ be another orthonormal basis of $T_xM$. Then there exists $A=(a^i_j)\in O(n)$ such that $\tilde{e}_j=a^i_je_i$. Then
$$
\sum_{j}S(\tilde{e}_j,\tilde{e}_j)=\sum_{j}S\left(
\sum_{k}a^k_je_k,\sum_{l}a^l_je_l
\right)=\sum_k\sum_l\left(\sum_ja^k_ja^l_j\right)S(e_k,e_l)=\sum_{k}\sum_l\delta_{kl}S(e_k,e_l)=\sum_{k}S(e_k,e_k).
$$

My question: It seems that the symmetric condition for $S$ is unnecessary? Or my proof is wrong?

Any correction or hints are appreciated.

Comment: You are right, it is not necessary to use the symmetry to define the trace.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.